# How to show an alert on screen if no option has been selected from a checkbox in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I am currently working on a form. I want to display an alert if no option has been selected from the checklist by the user. I have seen many posts related to this problem but none helped much. I don't have any idea of coding in JavaScript. My code is below:

**index.php**

```
<form name='form1' method="post" action="checkbox_value.php" >
    <div class="dropdownstay">
        <select name="city" class="option3" id="dropdown">
            <option value="1" id="1" style="font-size:20px; font-family:Monotype Corsiva;">Lahore</option>
            <option value="2" id="2" style="font-size:20px; font-family:Monotype Corsiva;">Dubai </option>
            <option value="3" id="3" style="font-size:20px; font-family:Monotype Corsiva;">Newyork</option>
            <option value="4" id="4" style="font-size:20px; font-family:Monotype Corsiva;">Canberra</option>
            <option value="5" id="5" style="font-size:20px; font-family:Monotype Corsiva;">Kuala Lampur</option>
            <br>

        </select>

        <!--end for drop down -->
    </div>

    </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="reservation">
        <ul>
            <li class="span1_of_1">
                <h5>What you want in hotel?</h5>
                <br>

                <section title="preferences">

                        <input type="checkbox" value="is_pool" id="pool" name="check_list[]" checked />
                        <text style="font-size:20px; font-family: Times New Roman;"> Pool </text>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="is_gym" id="gym" name="check_list[]" checked />
                        <text style="font-size:20px; font-family: Times New Roman;"> Gym </text>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="is_beach" id="beach" name="check_list[]" />
                        <text style="font-size:20px; font-family: Times New Roman;"> Beach </text>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="is_spa" id="spa" name="check_list[]" />
                        <text style="font-size:20px; font-family: Times New Roman;"> Spa </text>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="is_wifi" id="wifi" name="check_list[]" checked />
                        <text style="font-size:20px; font-family: Times New Roman;"> Wifi </text>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="is_familyoriented" id="family" name="check_list[]" />
                        <text style="font-size:20px; font-family: Times New Roman;"> Family Friendly</text>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="is_economical" id="economical" name="check_list[]" />
                        <text style="font-size:20px; font-family: Times New Roman;"> Economical </text>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>

                </section>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>

</li>
```

Tried to implement javascript code by using select tags but then removed them when I got to now that select tags are for drop down lists.

The problem is that it doesn't display an alert if the user doesn't select any option from the checklist and redirects to checkbox_value.php page. I cannot figure out how to implement validation for checkbox scenario. I want to redirect it to that page only if any option has been checked from the list. Any help to achieve this task shall be highly appreciable.

Comment: Why do you open your form twice? 
Do you want the form validation only for the first select or for all of them?
Why did you choose to include inline CSS?

Comment: sorry that must be editing mistake. I havent opened it twice in my code.

Comment: ignore one of the form openings

Comment: Please take some time to see how and why HTML should be separated from CSS. You will be thankful when you change your mind about a font(size).

Answer (score 0):

Your Best bet is to make an Option with a separated value (maybe 0, maybe "null") and whenever that is selected, display the warning.

```js
function validInput() {
  if (document.querySelector("select[name=city]").value == 0) {
      alert("You haven't selected any City!");
    }
  }
```

```html
<select name="city" class="option3" id="dropdown" onchange="validInput()">
  <option value="0" id="0" style="font-size:20px; font-family:Monotype Corsiva;">Select a City....</option>
  <option value="1" id="1" style="font-size:20px; font-family:Monotype Corsiva;">Lahore</option>
  <option value="2" id="2" style="font-size:20px; font-family:Monotype Corsiva;">Dubai </option>
  <option value="3" id="3" style="font-size:20px; font-family:Monotype Corsiva;">Newyork</option>
  <option value="4" id="4" style="font-size:20px; font-family:Monotype Corsiva;">Canberra</option>
  <option value="5" id="5" style="font-size:20px; font-family:Monotype Corsiva;">Kuala Lampur</option>
  <br>
</select>
```

Comment: Seems like the snippet isn't working, I am trying to fix that as of now...

Comment: I want to check if the options from the preference checklist have been selected or not.. Please guide me regarding the preference checklist as I tried to implement this code that you wrote for the preference list but it didnt make alert appear on the screen.